# Random Integer filling an array is not producing only integers

Tags: java, arrays, netbeans, random, integer

I have code to fill an array with 10 integers but for some reason it is not only filling it with integers. EX. [I@5483cd or [I@1690726
Anyone know why?

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int[] array = new int[10];
    int length = array.length;

    for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
        array[i] = (int)(Math.random () * 10); 
    }
    System.out.println(array);
}
```

Answer (score 4):

`System.out.println(array)`  is printing the hashcode for the array, not the values inside the array.   Iterate over the values in the array and print those, like this:

```
for (int val : array)
{
   System.out.println(val);
}
```

Even simpler, use:  `Arrays.toString(array)`.   See [What's the simplest way to print a Java array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/409784/simplest-way-to-print-an-array-in-java)

Answer (score 0):

As other answers say, println is printing [hashcode](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#hashCode%28%29) of the array. If you want to see array's contents, you can iterate over every element and print it OR you can use [Arrays.toString()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#toString%28int%5B%5D%29) methods.

```
import java.util.Arrays;
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(array));
```

If you have multidimensional arrays, use [Arrays.deepToString()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#deepToString%28java.lang.Object%5b%5d%29). Explore [Arrays](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html) class for more such utility methods.